# GCC freaking out when I use -static

Tags: c, gcc, botnet

I'm trying to compile a simple botnet I made, with the command `gcc -static -lpthread client.c` but every time i do it, it throws these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

It compiles fine whenever I compile without `-static` but I can't figure it out. You can find the code [here](https://pastebin.com/42tsBduZ). For the record this simple botnet is based off of bashlite, but has no actual DDoS functions, and cannot do any real harm. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have static versions of those libraries installed?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I think I do... How would I install a static link of pthread, and what library is it trying to link with `-lc`?

Comment: libc is the C standard library.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths how would I get static versions installed?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it when I did `yum install glibc-static`